# Conecting forms to admin page in django

Tags: python, django

I´m making my own portfolio and I wanna be able to see the messages that people sent me in the admin page but I don't seem to be able to make it so when someone submits the message it saves in the model and "broadcasts" in the admin page.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Messages(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    website = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Messages

class Messages(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'name'}), required=True, label='', max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'email'}), required=True, label='', max_length=50)
    website = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'website'}),required=False, label='', max_length=50)
    text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'text'}), required=True, label='', max_length=500)
    bot = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput, validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])

    class Meta():
        model = Messages
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseNotFound
from django.template import Template, Context
from . import forms

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def portfolio(request):
    return render(request, 'portfolio.html')

def certificate(request):
    return render(request, 'certificate.html')

def contact(request):

    form = forms.Messages()

    if request.method == 'post':

        form = form.Messages(request.post)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return thankyou(request)

        else:
            print('CONTACT ERROR')

    return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form':form})

def thankyou(request):
    return render(request, 'thankyou.html')
```

**Admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from toni.models import Messages

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Messages)
```

Comment: please describe the problem you're having. At a glance this code looks ok, except for `form = Messages(request.post)`, which with the way you've imported things should be `form = forms.Messages(request.post)` (but this will throw an error as soon as you submit the form, so you'd know about this if the code is really exactly as posted here). Incidentally I think it's bad style to use the name `Messages` for both the model and the form, `MessageForm` would be more usual for the form.

Comment: @RobinZigmond When I enter the admin page in Django it appears Messages because of the model but when I submit something in the contact form the info inputted by the user doesn't appear in the message menu of the admin page!          https://imgur.com/a/RWH1PZF                                                                                        https://imgur.com/a/pKhx6o6

Comment: so the messages submitted by the user aren't getting saved to the database then? Have you checked this directly (eg by running a query against the DB, either SQL or through Django's model query methods)? And assuming the data isn't saving, what happens when you submit the form? Any errors in the terminal? Do you get redirected to the thankyou page as intended?

Comment: @RobinZigmond i dont get any errors but i dont get redirected either

Comment: Ah, I've just realised the problem! You have `if request.method == 'post'` - but Django's capitalises the request method, so you should be checking against `'POST'`

Comment: @RobinZigmond Still doesn't work! Now it's saying that 'messages have no attribute messages'

Comment: simple typo - `form.Messages` should be `forms.Messages`. (I find it hard to believe you couldn't have debugged this yourself.)

Comment: Note that the recommended name in Django is the singular `Message` instead of `Messages`. By using the same name for your form and model, you risk having bugs. The usual approach would be to name the form `MessageForm`, but you could also do `from . import models` then use `models.Message` everywhere to avoid the clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is case sensitive. The `request.method` will always be uppercase, and the post data is stored in `request.POST`. Change the code to:

```
if request.method == 'POST':

    form = forms.Messages(request.POST)
```

You can debug problems like this by adding more `print()` lines. For example, you could have added `print("in the post")` after `if request.method == 'post':`. Then when you saw that the line was never printed, you could have added `print(request.method)`. Hopefully you would then spot the mismatch between `'post'` and `'POST'`.

Comment: wow, over an hour since the question was asked and you posted this answer at the exact same moment I'd just realised the issue myself (and posted as such in a comment). To be fair I only just came back to this after seeing the OP clarifying that they weren't getting redirected, which made me look a bit more closely at the possible outcomes from the view function.

Comment: thanks, but I'm not "possessive" of my answers, you found it independently and I'm happy with that. Helping the OP with their problem is the main thing.

Comment: Thats the error that i´m getting when i submit a new contact message in the website: https://imgur.com/a/XlrpTOe

Comment: Please don't link to images of errors in future. Copy and paste the full traceback in your question. As pointed out by @RobinZigmond, it should be `forms.Messages(request.POST)`.